# Looping through Youtube Search JSON response

Tags: json, vbscript, asp-classic

I am using ASPJson for working with ASP and JSON (it used to be hosted here a while ago http://www.aspjson.com/ but that site is no longer live, but the code I got from that site is here: https://pastebin.com/LJzikNAT)

This is my call to Youtube - example:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&q=london&type=video&key=[my_key]
```

That returns this JSON data:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/o9DTjpevDXudxmhkLef6i-kAnRE\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "regionCode": "GB",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/Qq093B1iIdU7htjV5jYf2Erqxgk\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "5DniDm9epIY"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/gbHSPn7IT-2OJG19vQZzKKTbG1s\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "Zlu542Tx8Fc"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/KQSQBNAk2ArZd_XrpDOIfiMT0XM\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "2tufxwCyrmE"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/wrbmiGkrH9v_QvtNpoIurXH9YQc\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "1XU8AOZ0Inw"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/2sdAsprKoDKIt8mNVYd8prR8uVA\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "vUO6kYLb6As"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

This is my ASP code to try and loop through the results:

```vb
<!--#INCLUDE file="../dist/asp/c.asp" -->
<!--#INCLUDE file="../dist/asp/aspJSON.asp" -->
<%
my_api = "my_key"
sendstring1 = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&q=chester&type=video&key="&my_api&""
Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objXML.Open "GET", sendstring1 , false
objXML.Send()

BackFromGoogle1 = objXML.responseText

Set oJSON = New aspJSON
oJSON.loadJSON(BackFromGoogle1)

For Each result In oJSON.data("items")
    Set this = oJSON.data("items").item(thingy)
    var_id = this.item("id").item("videoId")
    embed_code = "<iframe width='800' height='450' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/"&var_id&"?rel=0&amp;wmode=opaque' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"
    response.write embed_code   
Next
%>
```

The trouble is that as I loop through it, the ID returned in the `var_id` variable is always `5DniDm9epIY`, which is the ID of the first video - it doesn't seem to be changing each time through the loop, and I'm not sure why?

The `var_id` is displayed 5 times, so the code can see that there are 5 notes in the "items" collection, but it doesn't appear to go to the next node each time through the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using VBscript to access all values in JSON data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610139/using-vbscript-to-access-all-values-in-json-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `For Each` never references references the `result` object which will contain the current enumerated value.

Setting `this` to `oJSON.data("items").item(thingy)` will just reference the first enumerated value in the `oJSON.data("items")` collection. Not sure what `thingy` is but if you copied this code from somewhere else that should be the object you are enumerating with, in this case `result` should be used *(seems like you got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30802632/692942) then changed `thingy` to `result` in the `For Each` but not where it was used in the code)*.

Change that line to

```vb
Set this = oJSON.data("items").item(result)
```

to return a reference to the current enumerated object in the `oJSON.data("items")` collection.

---

Realised I've wrote about this before but been a while since I used this library.

[A: Using VBscript to access all values in JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41610976/692942)