# Parse Json string to Classic ASP page

Tags: json, vbscript, asp-classic

What is the best way to parse json string into classic asp using a library?

```
Dim jsonString
jsonString = {"date":"4/28/2017","custType":"100","vehicle":"1"}
```

Would like to have

```
response.write("<li> date :" & json("date") & "</li>")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using VBscript to access all values in JSON data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610139/using-vbscript-to-access-all-values-in-json-data)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn there are plenty of libraries for parsing JSON in Classic ASP.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn There are still tons legacy projects using Classic ASP.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - also, you can use Jscript rather than VBScript as your server side language in Classic ASP. JScript offers native handling of JSON

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it working:

Using https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON

```
Dim jsonString
jsonString = {"date":"4/28/2017","custType":"100","vehicle":"1"}

Dim jsonObj, outputObj
set jsonObj = new JSONobject
set outputObj = jsonObj.parse(jsonString)

response.write("<li> date :" & outputObj("date") & "</li>")
response.write("<li> custType :" & outputObj("custType") & "</li>")
response.write("<li> vehicle :" & outputObj("vehicle") & "</li>")
```

If you need to iterate through the single object use **outputObj.pairs**

```
Dim props, prop
props = outputObj.pairs
for each prop in props
    response.write prop.name & " : " & prop.value & "<br>"
next
```

as referenced https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON/issues/20

Comment: It's a really good library is that one, glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

As a quick solution for simple json structure and escaped values, this simple function returns the key values by splitting the json string on double quotes `chr(34)`:

```
function getKeyValue(JsonString,key)
    myarray=split(JsonString,key,-1,1)
    if ubound(myarray)>0 then
        myarray2=split(myarray(1),chr(34),-1,1)
        getKeyValue=myarray2(2)
    else
        getKeyValue=""
    end if
end function
```

usage:

```
response.write("<li> date :" & getKeyValue(Your_Json_String_Here,"date") & "</li>")
```

Answer (score 0):

' >>> A hundred times faster!

```
public function GetJsonObject( str_json )
    dim obj_script: Set obj_script = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
    obj_script.Language = "JScript"
    obj_script.Eval("var obj_json = " & str_json)
    set GetJsonObject = obj_script.Eval("obj_json")
end function

dim str_json: str_json = "{ date :'4/28/2017', custType: 100, vehicle: 1 }"
dim obj_json: set obj_json = GetJsonObject(str_json)

response.write("date :" & obj_json.date & "<br />")
response.write("custType :" & obj_json.custType & "<br />")
response.write("vehicle :" & obj_json.vehicle & "<br />")
```

' >>> no lib to include and when the JSON is very long, it works super fast also, not with lib "aspJSON".  Plus fields can be read directly, no string like xxx("vehicle")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).